# Unable to get `std::enable_if` to work for unscoped enum

Tags: c++, templates, enums

I'm trying to build a utility `ToString` function that either calls `std::to_string` or a custom `to_string` method defined somewhere else. This is what I came up with for version 1.0:

**Context**

The code here is a close approximation to what I'm working with for context. I have enums from a 3rd party library that are defined using the C stlye definition, as well as enums I've defined using the C++ style.

```
//From my 3rd party library
namespace ThirdPartyNamespace
{
    typedef enum
    {
        UnscopedValue
    } Unscoped;
}

//Defined in Scoped.h
namespace MyNamespace 
{
    enum class Scoped
    {
        ScopedValue
    };

    static std::string to_string(Scoped value)
    {
        return "Enums::Scoped";
    }
}

//Defined in Helpers.h, contains to_string methods for the enums in the 3rd party library
namespace Helpers 
{
    static std::string to_string(ThirdPartyNamespace::Unscoped value)
    {
        return "Enums::Unscoped";
    }    
}
```

**Calling Code**

```
ThirdPartyNamespace::Unscoped x = ThirdPartyNamespace::UnscopedValue;
MyNamespace::Scoped y = MyNamespace::Scoped::ScopedValue;

std::cout << Utilities::ToString(x) << std::endl;
std::cout << Utilities::ToString(y) << std::endl;
```

**Utility Code**

```
namespace Utilities
{
    template <typename T>
    std::string ToString(const T& value)
    {
        using std::to_string;

        return to_string(value);
    }
}
```

This compiles and works for `Scoped` but writes the integer value for `Unscoped`. I did some research and it seemed like to fix this I would need to use `std::enable_if` for my enum types. After some research on how `std::enable_if` works and SFINAE I came up with what I thought would work:

**Utility Code**

```
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_enum<T>::value>* = nullptr>
static std::string ToString(const T& value)
{
    using std::to_string;

    return to_string(value);
}

template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
static std::string ToString(const T& value)
{
    return to_string(value);
}
```

However, this does not compile. Specifically for `Unscoped` it gives throws a `'to_string': identifier not found` error (I verified that was the error by commenting out the call with `Unscoped` and it compiled and worked as expected).

My question is, why does the compiler fail to find my custom `to_string` method?

A bonus question: From my reading I found that `::type* = nullptr` "is setting a default value to the template 'type' parameter equal to 'nullptr'"([Source](http://codeofthedamned.com/index.php/enable_if#c467)), what exactly does that mean and why would one want a default value here?

Comment: Why would you expect the compiler to scan all namespaces in search for `to_string` ?

Comment: It's unrelated to scoped/unscoped enums. It's ADL that finds a viable `MyNamespace ::to_string` because the scoped enum happens to also belong to that namespace.

Comment: https://github.com/Neargye/magic_enum

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki I don't know why I thought ADL would search through namespaces. I tried changing the `Helpers` namespace to match the third party namespace and of course now it works. I appreciate the information, I'll need to research ADL a little more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need either

- move

  ```
  std::string to_string(ThirdPartyNamespace::Unscoped value)
  ```

  into namespace `ThirdPartyNamespace` to be found thanks to ADL
- or, change your `ToString` to

  ```
  template <typename T>
  std::string ToString(const T& value)
  {
      using std::to_string;
      using Helpers::to_string;

      return to_string(value);
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks Jarod42, that's what I ended up doing!